# MVC Child Only Action causes stackoverflow with attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

I have a route define for controller using attribute routing

```
[RoutePrefix("blog")]
public class BlogController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("detail")]
   public ActionResult Detail()
   {
      return Content("hello");
   }
}
```

I have a child only action that is being render in `_Layout.cshtml`

```
public class NotificationController : Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return PartialView("_Notification");
    }
}
```

inside `_Layout.cshtml`

```
@{ 
    try
    {
         Html.RenderAction("Index", "Notification");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       //never hit in case of exception, not sure why
    }
}
```

when I do a `GET` request on `/blog/detail`, everything works but when I do a `POST` request on `/blog/detail`, it throws `stackoverflow exception` inside `_Layout.cshtml` where it is trying to render `partial view`.

Further more, if I remove `[Route("detail")]` from Detail action, and then do a `POST` request on `/blog/detail`, the server reject a call and return `404` in `response`. That is what I'm expecting by keeping the `Route` attribute but not sure why it behaves differently.

Comment: where is your httppost code?? where is the post method code

Comment: I don't have `httpost` code for `/blog/detail` but in real application where the `PCI` scan run, somehow it make a post request on `/blog/detail` that is where it is crashing the site due to `stackoverflow` exception. So it should return 404 when someone make a `post` request on `/blog/detail` like it does when I remove the `[Route]` attribute.